# Add array to itself in foreach without duplicating?

Tags: php, arrays, foreach

```
   public function GetOpsPremiums()
    {
        // Get the Cost Multiplier
        $costMulti  = $this->GetCostMultiplier();
        // Get the Prem Ops
        $premOps    = $this->GetPremOpsEL();
        // Get the Factors
        $factors    = $this->GetFactors();

        // Get the full class array
        $classArray = $this->GetClassArray();

        foreach ($classArray as $key => $values) {
            $classTotalHalved = $values / 1000;
            $mainMultiplier = $costMulti * $premOps[$key] * $factors[$key]['premops'];
            $premium = $classTotalHalved * $mainMultiplier;
            $opsPremiums = array(
                            $key => round($premium)
                        );
        }
        return $opsPremiums;
    }
```

I want $opsPremiums to not just iterate 1 at a time. I need it to iterate and add itself to itself.

I tried

```
foreach ($opsPremiums as $key2 => $values2) {
     $opsPremiums = array(
                         $key => round($premium)
                    );
}
```

Can someone explain to me what I need to do in order to get the $opsPremium to stack itself neatly into a single array?

Comment: use `print_r($opsPremiums);` to show us how does `$opsPremiums` looks like, what's the expected output after `GetOpsPremiums()` is called ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

should be so

```
foreach ($opsPremiums as $key2 => $values2) {

 $opsPremiums[] = array(
                     $key => round($premium)
                );
}
```

Comment: Using something similar to this; I was able to get it to work. I was missing the [] on $opsPremiums[]. I was able to create the array list I wanted.

Answer (score 2):

I'm a little unsure of what you mean, but are you trying to return all the results in $opsPremium?

The issue is your setting it as an array on each iteration rather than adding to it.

```
$opsPremium = array();
foreach ($classArray as $key => $values) {
        $classTotalHalved = $values / 1000;
        $mainMultiplier = $costMulti * $premOps[$key] * $factors[$key]['premops'];
        $premium = $classTotalHalved * $mainMultiplier;
        $opsPremiums[] = array(
                        $key => round($premium)
                    );
}
return $opsPremiums;
```

Storing $opsPremium outside the loop and adding to it each time will do that for you.

My apologies if this is not what you were asking.

Answer (score 0):

It seems your very confused with the terminology of how to speak about your problem.  I believe what you should have asked is, I want to add some extra items including itself to an array for return.  In which case the magic you need is array concatenation.  Im a little unsure of what your array requires, but you can append anything to any php array with the [] operator.  If you respond with a more detailed question perhaps I can help you further.

Depending on what your are adding to your array, for the program to function you may need to use the array_merge, array_push.